# Unexpected End-of-file Error, Looked for common causes and can't find any

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to edit a branch of an open-source project, but one of the files fails to compile with a "C1004: Unexpected end of file" error.

I've seen these in the past, and I know the cause is usually a missing } somewhere or a missing ; after a struct or class definition.  However, I've looked over this code carefully and can't for the life of me find any unmatched brackets.  Is there anything else that might be causing this error?  Can anyone see a problem with the existing code?

Visual Studio is calling out the error for this file specifically, which makes me think the problem is there and not with any of the header files.  Am I correct about that, or could there be a problem in one of the custom header files instead?

`````
 *  socket_win32.c
 *
 *  Copyright 2013-2018 Michael Zillgith
 *
 *  This file is part of libIEC61850.
        <rest of header redacted for space>*/

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include "lib_memory.h"
#include "hal_socket.h"
#include "stack_config.h"


#ifndef __MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR
struct tcp_keepalive {
    u_long  onoff;
    u_long  keepalivetime;
    u_long  keepaliveinterval;
};
#endif

#define SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS    _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR,4)

struct sSocket {
    SOCKET fd;
    uint32_t connectTimeout;
};

struct sServerSocket {
    SOCKET fd;
    int backLog;
};

struct sHandleSet {
   fd_set handles;
   SOCKET maxHandle;
};

HandleSet Handleset_new(void)
{
   HandleSet result = (HandleSet) GLOBAL_MALLOC(sizeof(struct sHandleSet));

   if (result != NULL) {
       FD_ZERO(&result->handles);
       result->maxHandle = INVALID_SOCKET;
   }
   return result;
}

void Handleset_reset(HandleSet self)
{
    FD_ZERO(&self->handles);
    self->maxHandle = INVALID_SOCKET;
}

void Handleset_addSocket(HandleSet self, const Socket sock)
{
   if (self != NULL && sock != NULL && sock->fd != INVALID_SOCKET) {
       FD_SET(sock->fd, &self->handles);

       if ((sock->fd > self->maxHandle) || (self->maxHandle == INVALID_SOCKET)){
           self->maxHandle = sock->fd;
       }
   }
}

int Handleset_waitReady(HandleSet self, unsigned int timeoutMs)
{
   int result;

   if (self != NULL && self->maxHandle >= 0) {
       struct timeval timeout;

       timeout.tv_sec = timeoutMs / 1000;
       timeout.tv_usec = (timeoutMs % 1000) * 1000;
       result = select(self->maxHandle + 1, &self->handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   } else {
       result = -1;
   }

   return result;
}

void Handleset_destroy(HandleSet self)
{
   GLOBAL_FREEMEM(self);
}

static bool wsaStartupCalled = false;
static int socketCount = 0;

void Socket_activateTcpKeepAlive(Socket self, int idleTime, int interval, int count)
{
    struct tcp_keepalive keepalive;
    DWORD retVal=0;

    keepalive.onoff = 1;
    keepalive.keepalivetime = CONFIG_TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE * 1000;
    keepalive.keepaliveinterval = CONFIG_TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL * 1000;

     if (WSAIoctl(self->fd, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &keepalive, sizeof(keepalive),
                NULL, 0, &retVal, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
     {
         if (DEBUG_SOCKET){
                printf("WIN32_SOCKET: WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) failed: %d\n",
                    WSAGetLastError());
         }
     }
}


static void setSocketNonBlocking(Socket self)
{
    unsigned long mode = 1;
    int tcpNoDelay = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(self->fd, FIONBIO, &mode) != 0) {
        if (DEBUG_SOCKET){
            printf("WIN32_SOCKET: failed to set socket non-blocking!\n");
        }
    }

    /* activate TCP_NODELAY */

    setsockopt(self->fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (const char*)&tcpNoDelay, sizeof(int));
}

static bool prepareServerAddress(const char* address, int port, struct sockaddr_in* sockaddr)
{

    memset((char *) sockaddr , 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    if (address != NULL) {
        struct hostent *server;
        server = gethostbyname(address);

        if (server == NULL) return false;

        memcpy((char *) &sockaddr->sin_addr.s_addr, (char *) server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    }
    else{
        sockaddr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    }
    sockaddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr->sin_port = htons(port);

    return true;
}

static bool wsaStartUp()
{
    if (wsaStartupCalled == false) {
        int ec;
        WSADATA wsa;

        if ((ec = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa)) != 0) {
            if (DEBUG_SOCKET)
                printf("WIN32_SOCKET: winsock error: code %i\n", ec);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            wsaStartupCalled = true;
            return true;
        }

    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

static void wsaShutdown()
{
    if (wsaStartupCalled) {
        if (socketCount == 0) {
            WSACleanup();
            wsaStartupCalled = false;
        }

    }
}

ServerSocket TcpServerSocket_create(const char* address, int port)
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = NULL;
    int ec;
    SOCKET listen_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int optionReuseAddr = 1;

    if (wsaStartUp() == false){
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!prepareServerAddress(address, port, &server_addr)){
        return NULL;
    }

    listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        if (DEBUG_SOCKET){
            printf("WIN32_SOCKET: socket failed with error: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        wsaShutdown();

        return NULL;
    }


    setsockopt(listen_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&optionReuseAddr, sizeof(int));

    ec = bind(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    if (ec == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (DEBUG_SOCKET){
            printf("WIN32_SOCKET: bind failed with error:%i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        closesocket(listen_socket);

        wsaShutdown();

        return NULL;
    }

    serverSocket = (ServerSocket) GLOBAL_MALLOC(sizeof(struct sServerSocket));

    serverSocket->fd = listen_socket;
    serverSocket->backLog = 10;

    setSocketNonBlocking((Socket) serverSocket);

    socketCount++;

    return serverSocket;
}

void ServerSocket_listen(ServerSocket self)
{
    listen(self->fd, self->backLog);
}

Socket ServerSocket_accept(ServerSocket self)
{
    int fd;

    Socket conSocket = NULL;

    fd = accept(self->fd, NULL, NULL);

    if (fd >= 0) {
        conSocket = (Socket) GLOBAL_CALLOC(1, sizeof(struct sSocket));
        conSocket->fd = fd;

        socketCount++;

        setSocketNonBlocking(conSocket);
    }

    return conSocket;
}

void ServerSocket_setBacklog(ServerSocket self, int backlog)
{
    self->backLog = backlog;
}

void ServerSocket_destroy(ServerSocket self)
{
    closesocket(self->fd);
    socketCount--;
    wsaShutdown();
    GLOBAL_FREEMEM(self);
}

Socket TcpSocket_create()
{
    Socket self = NULL;
    int sock;

    if (wsaStartUp() == false){
        return NULL;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        self = (Socket) GLOBAL_MALLOC(sizeof(struct sSocket));

        self->fd = sock;
        self->connectTimeout = 5000;

        socketCount++;
    }
    else {
        if (DEBUG_SOCKET)
            printf("SOCKET: failed to create socket (error code=%i)\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    return self;
}

void Socket_setConnectTimeout(Socket self, uint32_t timeoutInMs)
{
    self->connectTimeout = timeoutInMs;
}

bool Socket_connect(Socket self, const char* address, int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    fd_set fdSet;
    struct timeval timeout;

    if (!prepareServerAddress(address, port, &serverAddress)){
        return false;
    }

    setSocketNonBlocking(self);

    FD_ZERO(&fdSet);
    FD_SET(self->fd, &fdSet);

    if (connect(self->fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK){
            return false;
        }
    }

    timeout.tv_sec = self->connectTimeout / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (self->connectTimeout % 1000) * 1000;

    if (select(self->fd + 1, NULL, &fdSet, NULL, &timeout) <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

//apa+++
/* Portable IPv6/IPv4 version of sockaddr.  Based on RFC 2553.
   Pad to force 8 byte alignment and maximum size of 128 bytes. */

/*
 * Desired design of maximum size and alignment
 */
#ifndef _WS2DEF_
#define _SS_MAXSIZE    128
#define _SS_ALIGNSIZE  (sizeof (__int64)) 
#endif
/*
 * Definitions used for sockaddr_storage structure paddings design.
 */
#define _SS_PAD1SIZE   (_SS_ALIGNSIZE - sizeof (short))
#define _SS_PAD2SIZE   (_SS_MAXSIZE - (sizeof (short) \
                       + _SS_PAD1SIZE \
                       + _SS_ALIGNSIZE))

#ifndef _WS2DEF_
struct sockaddr_storage {
    short ss_family;
    char __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];  /* pad to 8 */
    __int64 __ss_align;        /* force alignment */
    char __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];  /*  pad to 128 */
};

#define INET6_ADDRSTRLEN 65
//end apa+++

char* Socket_getPeerAddress(Socket self)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    int addrLen = sizeof(addr);
    char addrString[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 7];
    int addrStringLen = INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 7;
    int port;
    bool isIPv6;
    char* clientConnection;

    getpeername(self->fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &addrLen);

    if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET)  {
        struct sockaddr_in* ipv4Addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &addr;
        port = ntohs(ipv4Addr->sin_port);
        ipv4Addr->sin_port = 0;
        WSAAddressToString((LPSOCKADDR) ipv4Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage), NULL, 
            (LPSTR) addrString, (LPDWORD) &addrStringLen);
        isIPv6 = false;
    }
    else if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET6){
        struct sockaddr_in6* ipv6Addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*) &addr;
        port = ntohs(ipv6Addr->sin6_port);
        ipv6Addr->sin6_port = 0;
        WSAAddressToString((LPSOCKADDR) ipv6Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage), NULL, 
            (LPSTR) addrString, (LPDWORD) &addrStringLen);
        isIPv6 = true;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
    clientConnection = (char*) GLOBAL_MALLOC(strlen(addrString) + 9);

    if (isIPv6){
        sprintf(clientConnection, "[%s]:%i", addrString, port);
    } else {
        sprintf(clientConnection, "%s:%i", addrString, port);
    }

    return clientConnection;
}

char* Socket_getPeerAddressStatic(Socket self, char* peerAddressString)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    int addrLen = sizeof(addr);
    char addrString[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 7];
    int addrStringLen = INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 7;
    int port;

    bool isIPv6;

    getpeername(self->fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &addrLen);

    if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in* ipv4Addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &addr;
        port = ntohs(ipv4Addr->sin_port);
        ipv4Addr->sin_port = 0;
        WSAAddressToString((LPSOCKADDR) ipv4Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage), NULL,
                (LPSTR) addrString, (LPDWORD) & addrStringLen);
        isIPv6 = false;
    }
    else if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET6) {
        struct sockaddr_in6* ipv6Addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*) &addr;
        port = ntohs(ipv6Addr->sin6_port);
        ipv6Addr->sin6_port = 0;
        WSAAddressToString((LPSOCKADDR) ipv6Addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage), NULL,
                (LPSTR) addrString, (LPDWORD) & addrStringLen);
        isIPv6 = true;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (isIPv6){
        sprintf(peerAddressString, "[%s]:%i", addrString, port);
    } else {
        sprintf(peerAddressString, "%s:%i", addrString, port);
    }

    return peerAddressString;
}

int Socket_read(Socket self, uint8_t* buf, int size)
{
    int bytes_read = recv(self->fd, (char*) buf, size, 0);

    if (bytes_read == 0){ // peer has closed socket
        return -1;
    }

    if (bytes_read == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return bytes_read;
}

int Socket_write(Socket self, uint8_t* buf, int size)
{
    int bytes_sent = send(self->fd, (char*) buf, size, 0);

    if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();

        if (errorCode == WSAEWOULDBLOCK){
            bytes_sent = 0;
        } else {
            bytes_sent = -1;
        }
    }

    return bytes_sent;
}

void Socket_destroy(Socket self)
{
    if (self->fd != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(self->fd);
    }

    socketCount--;
    wsaShutdown();

    GLOBAL_FREEMEM(self);
}````
`````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
#ifndef _WS32DEF_
```

has no corrsponding `#endif`

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef _WS2DEF_
struct sockaddr_storage {
    short ss_family;
    char __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];  /* pad to 8 */
    __int64 __ss_align;        /* force alignment */
    char __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];  /*  pad to 128 */
};
#endif
```

This should work.